# Is the capture mechanic in Fire Emblem Fates worthwhile?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

Feel free to tailor your answer to routes but please keep your answers spoiler free. From what I read here: http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Capture#Fates my interpretation is there's not much point to capturing units as they'd be effectively subpar to your named special snowflakes composing your army.

- Most captured units are very low grade units, having low growths and often bad starting stats. They also are limited to their starting class set, having no secondary class, and cannot form supports with any allied units.
- captured units may have unique enemy skills, such as Inevitable End, when fought and captured. However, upon recruitment, the enemy will lose any of the enemy-exclusive skills on them.

In particular it strikes me that in Birthright it's not worthwhile as you can already grind up your units.

For example can you rip skills off captured units and put them onto your named units? Would this make the capture mechanic worthwhile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture mechanic is useful as it helps you gain extra units that don't play a part in the main story. They are useful in classic mode as you will need them to replace lost units (e.g. losing Sakura/Jakob in Birthright meaning you don't have a healer) or just as disposable units in harder levels. They are probably most useful in Conquest.